# Jaspersoft - group Start New Page ignores print when expression

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a group header which contains a title, a short description and then in the details band I print out the content.

I've set it up so that for each new group (grouped by title) it should start on a new page. Now I want to make sure that I don't print the title and the short description if I don't have any content related to it. So I've made a field which checks for a unique id in the content and use that field in the group band properties print when expression and in my details band print when expression.

And that works, I no longer print the title and short description if there is no content related to it. Here's the problem, with this setup I get a lot of empty pages inside my report where it originally printed the title and short description without content. If I remove the Start New Page option in my group I no longer get these empty pages. So somehow my group starts a new page before checking my print when expression, then checks it and decides not to print the groups content.

Have I've done something wrong or is there any way to bypass this behavior?

Comment: You need to pass some relevant jrxml [mcve], its sounds to have a logical problem, you can't avoid the new page, this way maybe grouping in different way will do the trick (seems that you have a group that is not a group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Start New Page setting in the group I used a break element with a Print When Expression, this does exactly what I thought the Start New Page option would do.